# Microsoft Graph API BadRequest Current authenticated context is not valid

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to develop a simple background app to connect to my onedrive account (work) and regularly download some files.

I followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds

I have registered the app here https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/portal/register-app
I have written down the `client_id` and `client_secret`

To get an access token I make a POST request to

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
with the following form encoded data

```
{
    'client_id': 'clientid here',
    'client_secret': 'secret is here',
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
}
```

I get back an `access_token`

```
{'ext_expires_in': 0,
 'token_type': 'Bearer',
 'expires_in': 3600,
 'access_token': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciO---SHORTENED FOR BREVITY'}
```

Next I make a GET request (with `Bearer` header properly set) to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

and get this eror response (which I get for any endpoint fwiw)

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Current authenticated context is not valid for this request",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "91059f7d-c798-42a1-b3f7-2487f094486b",
      "date": "2017-08-05T12:40:33"
    }
  }
}
```

I have these permissions configured in the app setting
[image: permissions]

**Any ideas what might be wrong?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll file a bug to improve this awful error message.  The problem is that you are making a request using application permissions (client_credentials flow) - where there is no signed-in user context.  Your request is to `/me`, and `/me` is basically an alias for the signed-in user - and in this case there isn't one!

You should try a call to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` instead.  **But**, before you do that. In the app registration portal, you've selected *delegated* permissions, but you are calling with *application permissions*.  You should remove the delegated permissions, and select the appropriate application permissions - to call users, select *User.Read.All* for example.  Then make sure to consent/reconsent your app by going to the /adminconsent endpoint.

Please also read more on permissions and delegated and application permissions here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference

Hope this helps,

Comment: Dan, thank you! I've read more about OAuth2 and I see the issue here. Are the only supported flows the `client_credentials` and `authorization_code`? For my purpose I'd prefer to use the delegated permissions as I really only need access to the files the user can see, I don't need (and don't want) to access all of the Organization's files. Is the only way to do this to use the `authorization_code` which involves using `refresh_tokens`? Is there a way to get some kind of long-lived `refresh_token` or use the `grant_type=password`?

Comment: Please follow the guidance here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user for the authorization code flow and hadling refresh tokens which are long-lived.  Please do not use the password flow - there are very specific scenarios for this flow and it comes with a bunch of serious disadvantages - please see http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/.

Comment: @RobinNemeth Hi are you able to solve this issue ? I got exactly same issue with delegated permissions. mine is a backend app and I dont want popup a login form for user to authorize. The grant_type=password doesn't work for me for I keep getting Invalid password error when calling ../token api;.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT Hi Dan, according to the guidance we need to redirect user to endpoint /authorize which is basiclly a login page. Does this mean we can not skip this user action ? What if I want to fetch token with a backend app without user presence ?

Comment: @daniel you need to go through the consent screen and approve it at least once. After you go through the user consent, you get a refresh token that is valid for couple of days. After each exchange of `refresh_token` for `access_token` you get a new `refresh_token` which, when saved, you can use for further requests. I think you can continue to do this for at least 90 days so you don't need to do it too often

Comment: Thanks @RobinNemeth. Did you only use delegated permission ? if so what grant type do you use to get token ?

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: { "error": { "code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound", "message": "The identity of the calling application (truncated...)

Comment: I am getting the same error "code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",\r\n    "message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established."

Comment: @daniel were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

i used https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{Emailid}}/messages to get all the messages in my inbox

Answer (score 0):

In clientCredential flow you are accessing as an with Client secret or with client certificate . So Graph API no linger understands who is me. So you need use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<Your_userId> or https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<your_userprincipalname>.

eg.https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/1sd1353as..
or
eg.https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/John_doe@contso.com

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Where exactly on the reference doc has the info that made you understand Graph API did not understand .´Me´?